# Clear Xamarin Forms Modal Stack

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms application that uses a NavigationPage for normal screen navigation. From one of the screens (Stay Detail), I need to display a series of 4 sequential modal pages (like a wizard) that collects data to complete a process related to Stay Detail. Each page in the process has a "Cancel" button that should allow the user to cancel out of the wizard and return to Stay Detail. Here is the general flow:

```
            modal1 -> modal2 -> modal3 -> modal4
           /                                    \
 StayDetail                                      StayDetail
```

It's easy enough to do a PushModalAsync from StayDetail to launch modal1, then PushModalAsync/PopModalAsync to go between the individual modal pages. However, I can't figure out a clean way to exit out of the modal stack from the 2nd modal or later. What's the best way to do that?

Comment: i've had the same issue today. working on the answer i came up with

Comment: For anyone who does not want to go back all the way but return to a previous modal page, I have provided an answer in this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55613281/101087

Answer (score 0):

This solution will probably look overly complicated for your case, but it's what i'm using to communicate between modal actions to resolve dependencies (no account present, id missing, data deleted in the meantime etc) at random without losing type safety.

One way to think about wizards / a modal series is, that the next page depends on the previous and that mostly you will want to work  with the result of your child modal.

I hope this helps:

```
public static class ModalManager
{
    public static bool TryRespondModal<TData>(this IModalResponse<TData> source, TData data, bool autoPop = true, bool animate = false)
    {
        if (Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.ModalStack.Count <= 0)
            return false;

        source.ModalRequestComplete.SetResult(data);

        if (autoPop)
            Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopModalAsync(animate);

        return true;
    }

    public static Task<TData> GetResponseAsync<TData>(this IModalResponse<TData> source)
    {
        source.ModalRequestComplete = new TaskCompletionSource<TData>();
        return source.ModalRequestComplete.Task;
    }
}

public enum WizardState
{
    Indeterminate = 0,
    Complete = 1,
    Canceled = 2
}

public class WizardModel
{
    public WizardState State { get; set; }

    public List<string> Page1Values { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    public List<string> Page2Values { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    public List<string> Page3Values { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}

public abstract class WizardPage : IModalResponse<WizardModel>
{
    public WizardModel Model { get; set; }

    public ICommand NextCommand { get; set; }

    public ICommand PreviousCommand { get; set; }

    public ICommand CancelCommand { get; set; }

    protected WizardPage(WizardModel model)
    {
        Model = model;
        NextCommand = new Command(NextButtonPressed);
        PreviousCommand = new Command(PreviousButtonPressed);
        CancelCommand = new Command(PreviousButtonPressed);
    }

    protected abstract IModalResponse<WizardModel> GetNextPage();

    protected virtual void CancelButtonPressed()
    {
        Model.State = WizardState.Canceled;
        this.TryRespondModal(Model);
    }

    protected virtual void PreviousButtonPressed()
    {
        // you're dropping down on the level of dependent windows here so you can tell your previous modal window the result of the current response
        this.TryRespondModal(Model);
    }

    protected virtual async void NextButtonPressed()
    {
        var np = GetNextPage();
        if (Model.State == WizardState.Complete || np == null || (await np?.GetResponseAsync()).State == WizardState.Complete)
            PersistWizardPage();

        // all following modal windows must have run through - so you persist whatever your page has done, unless you do that on the last page anyway. and then tell the previous
        // modal window that you're done
        this.TryRespondModal(Model);
    }

    protected virtual void PersistWizardPage()
    {
        // virtual because i'm lazy
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public TaskCompletionSource<WizardModel> ModalRequestComplete { get; set; }
}

public class Page1 : WizardPage
{

    public Page1(WizardModel model) : base(model)
    {
    }

    protected override IModalResponse<WizardModel> GetNextPage()
    {
        return new Page2(Model);
    }
}

public class Page2 : WizardPage
{
    public Page2(WizardModel model) : base(model)
    {
    }

    protected override IModalResponse<WizardModel> GetNextPage()
    {
        return new Page3(Model);
    }
}

public class Page3 : WizardPage
{
    public Page3(WizardModel model) : base(model)
    {
    }

    protected override IModalResponse<WizardModel> GetNextPage()
    {
        return null;
    }

    protected override void NextButtonPressed()
    {
        this.Model.State = WizardState.Complete;
        base.NextButtonPressed();
    }
}

public interface IModalResponse<TResponseType>
{
    TaskCompletionSource<TResponseType> ModalRequestComplete { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: i guess that's where the stereotype of germans overengineering things comes from...