# How to remove particular page from modal stack?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have four pages page 1-page 2-page 3-page 4.I use push modal async for navigating forward. When I tap button click in page 4 it is navigating to the page2. But tapping back button in page 2 is showing all history of the stack pages. So how to remove the page from the modal stack. I also used navigation.Remove(page) but it throws an exception. Please guide.

```
foreach (var page in Navigation.ModalStack)
{
    if (page is Page3)
    {
        await PopModalPage();
    }
}

foreach (var page in Navigation.ModalStack)
{
    if (page is Page4)
    {
        await PopModalPage();
    }
}
```

To navigate to page 2 from page 4 I'm using this code 
Any optimized way than this??

Comment: Please provide an [mcve]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove a modal page from NavigationStack in Xamarin.Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37398962/how-to-remove-a-modal-page-from-navigationstack-in-xamarin-forms)

Comment: Question edited @NineBerry

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clear Xamarin Forms Modal Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36892044/clear-xamarin-forms-modal-stack)

Comment: How to remove the current page from stack

Comment: Hi @All pLease provide me solution

Comment: Hi @NineBerry from his code it also removes page 1 also from the stack. I don't want to remove page 1 from the modal stack.Please provide me solution

Comment: HI @All Please provide me solution

Comment: Hi @All I can't get clarity here so please guide

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following helper functions

```
/// <summary>
/// Class with extension methods for INavigation interface to help working with the modal page stack
/// </summary>
public static class ModalHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Unwinds the modal stack of the navigation until reaching a page with the given type
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="PageType"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="navigation">The navigation object of the current top page</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async static Task UnwindModalStackTo<PageType>(this INavigation navigation) where PageType : Page
    {
        await navigation.UnwindModalStackTo(p => p is PageType);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Unwinds the modal stack of the navigation until reaching the given page 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="navigation">The navigation object of the current top page</param>
    /// <param name="page">The page where to stop unwinding the modal stack</param>
    public async static Task UnwindModalStackTo(this INavigation navigation, Page page) 
    {
        await navigation.UnwindModalStackTo(p => p == page);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Unwinds the modal stack of the navigation until reaching a page that fulfils the predicate
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="navigation">The navigation object of the current top page</param>
    /// <param name="predicate">A function which tests whether to stop at a given page</param>
    public async static Task UnwindModalStackTo(this INavigation navigation, Func<Page, bool> predicate)
    {
        bool found = false;

        while (navigation != null && navigation.ModalStack.Count > 0)
        {
            // Get the current top page of the modal stack
            Page topPage = navigation.ModalStack[navigation.ModalStack.Count - 1];

            // Get the second page in the modal stack from the top (This one will become top next after we pop)
            Page parentPage;
            if (navigation.ModalStack.Count > 1)
            {
                parentPage = navigation.ModalStack[navigation.ModalStack.Count - 2];
            }
            else
            {
                parentPage = null;
            }

            // When the top page fulfills the predicate, stop
            if (predicate(topPage))
            {
                found = true;
                break;
            }

            // Pop the top page
            await navigation.PopModalAsync();

            // We need to use the navigation of the new top page from here on
            navigation = parentPage?.Navigation;
        }

        // When the target page was not found, throw an exception
        if (!found)
        {
            throw new Exception("Desired page not found in modal stack");
        }
    }

}
```

Note that after we have popped the top modal page from the stack, we have to use the Navigation from the new top page to continue on.

---

Example:

Imagine we have an app with five pages: MainPage, Page1, Page2, Page3, Page4.

Mainpage has a button to open Page1 modal, Page1 has a button to open Page2 modal, and so on.

In MainPage:

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page p = new Page1();
    await Navigation.PushModalAsync(p);
}
```

In Page1:

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page p = new Page2();
    await Navigation.PushModalAsync(p);
}
```

And so on...

Now in Page4 instead (in order to go back to Page2) we use the following code to close all open modal pages until we reach Page2.

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Navigation.UnwindModalStackTo<Page2>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks let me try this

Comment: This worked for me. You can still see modals being popped out with animation and all... but I think it's the only worthy response in many threads around here.

Comment: According to documentation, you should be able to pass `false` as an argument to `PopModalAsync` to prevent the animation. (Not tested)

Answer (score -2):

`RemovePage` only supports removing of specified page from `NavigationStack`.

Like this: `Navigation.RemovePage(Navigation.NavigationStack[Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 1]);`

You can refer this for more detail:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.inavigation?view=xamarin-forms

Answer (score -2):

If you want to go 2 pages back this will work

```
        Navigation.RemovePage(Navigation.NavigationStack[Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 2]);
        Navigation.RemovePage(this);
```

First we remove the page before the current page and then the current page.

Comment: How to remove the current page from stack??

Comment: @Tester Navigation.RemovePage(this);

Answer (score -3):

Please use `await Navigation.PopModalAsync()` and read through [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/modal) to get info about `ModalPages`.

**EDIT:**

Haven't tested it, but could help to understand the approach:

```
for (var i = Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
{
    if (Navigation.NavigationStack[i] is Page2)
    {
        return;
    }
    await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
}
```

Comment: After navigating from page 4 to page 2.it should not show me two pages in view(page 4 and page 3). Navigation.PopModalAsync() this remove a page from stack .How to remove multiple pages at a click. I need to remove page 4 and 3.

Comment: I called  PopModalPage()  method twice at page 4 button click. Issue resolved. But is this optimized way?

Comment: @Tester That's not good at all. That's not flexible, what if you would have to add a page between page 3 and 4?
There would be better to use `PopToRootAsync` and go to specific page from root page, or change your approach.

Comment: Pop to Root Async navigates to page 1 but I need to go to page 2.While using popto root async im getting this exception.:
System.InvalidOperationException: PopToRootAsync is not supported globally on Android, please use a NavigationPage.

Comment: @Tester As alternative approach your could get last `Page` from your `NavigationStack` and compare it's type with Page2, and pop `Pages` until you get desired `Page`.

Comment: can you share some code snippet for better understanding.

Comment: Can i use Modal Stack instead of navigation stack

Comment: @Tester try it.

Comment: How to remove current page from modal stack

Comment: @Tester `Navigation.PopModalAsync()` removes current page from nav. stack.

Comment: This does not work because the Navigation object used is bound to the current top modal page. As soon as this page is removed from the Modal stack, its Navigation object becomes empty and cannot be used for any further navigation. You pop multiple modal pages successively, you always have to switch to the new top page in the loop as shown in my answer.