# How to remove page from modal stack optimized way(specific)?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have four pages page 1-page 2-page 3-page 4.I use push modal async for navigating forward. When I tap button click in page 4 is using below code it is navigating to the page2.

```
foreach (var page in Navigation.ModalStack)
{
    if (page is Page3)
    {
        await PopModalPage();
    }
}

foreach (var page in Navigation.ModalStack)
{
    if (page is Page4)
    {
        await PopModalPage();
    }
}
```

To navigate to page 2 from page 4 I'm using this code Any optimized way than this??Please guide.

Comment: This would be better off in code review if the code works as is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove particular page from modal stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55570376/how-to-remove-particular-page-from-modal-stack)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

In your page 4, add below code to modal pop to page2:

```
private  void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gobackAsync();
}

public async void gobackAsync() {

    int totalModals = Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.ModalStack.Count;

    //i set currModal = 1 here to back to page 2, If you wan to go back to 3, you can set currModal = 2, etc...
    // remember to add flase in PopModalAsync to aviod the animation.

    for (int currModal = 1; currModal < totalModals; currModal++)
    {
        await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopModalAsync(false);
    }
}
```

I set currModal = 1 there to back to page 2, If you wan to go back to 3, you can set currModal = 2, etc...

Remember to add **flase** in `PopModalAsync` to aviod the animation.

Comment: @Tester Is my answer solved your problem? If yes, you can accept it.